# How can I pass abstract class types as a generic parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass **abstract class types** as a parameter to a generic method in TypeScript.

I'm working on an Entity-Component system in Typescript. This means I have entities, which are containers of components, and I can fetch any arbitrary component from them. Here's a minimal example:

```
abstract class Component { }
class PlayerController extends Component { }
class MonsterController extends Component { }
class LaserGun extends Component { }
class Collider extends Component { }
class Movement extends Component { } // etc, you get the idea

class Entity {
  public components: Component[] = [];

  public fetch<T extends Component>(componentType: { new(): T }): T | undefined {
    return this.components.find(c => c instanceof componentType) as T;
  }
}
```

Now I can fetch individual component types like this:

```
const entity = new Entity();
entity.components.push(new PlayerController());
entity.components.push(new Movement());
entity.components.push(new LaserGun());
const playerController = entity.fetch(PlayerController);
// ^ this variable controller is typed PlayerController,
// so I can use PlayerController-specific features.
```

[image: screenshot of the ability to do the above fetch]

However, I want to upgrade this structure by being able to request abstract types. For example, I could have other Weapons beside LaserGun, and just request any Weapon at all that's attached to the class without caring which kind of weapon it is, like this:

```
abstract class Weapon extends Component {
  public abstract attack(): void;
}
class LaserGun extends Weapon {
  public attack(): void { /* pew pew */ }
}
class Sword extends Weapon {
  public attack(): void { /* swish swish */ }
}
```

I can't actually fetch this abstract class though, because abstract classes don't have constructors, and TypeScript doesn't let me pass them as a parameter to the above method:

```
const weapon = entity.fetch(Weapon);
//                          ~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'typeof Weapon' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Weapon'.
//  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.ts(2345)
```

[image: screenshot of the error described in the above code block occurring in Visual Studio Code]

How can I update my `fetch()` method to allow me to pass any class type that extends Component, including abstract classes?

For now my workaround is to simply make Weapon a non-abstract class, but I'd like to know how to do this in a way that lets me use abstract classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [abstract construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) for that ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyMQG8EBfAWACgU0MAFVATxKh3Km2WRcEJAB4QyAEww4CxMpRoMm6BAFlikLj2j9BUYWMnS8hUuQRU6jVCpwCAlhKGjxRKVhNzzlpTYzqANxJceQNXdxlTUMsEAHpY4QhYABoEdmwAVwQAcxJECAALEgRHEmAGCutmBABRcnsIdgsGBAR8DJBke1gkTzMIMAAuD1l%20gG0AXQQAXgRJgG5K1vbO7oQAMzzYAoAeABUwoxGo8gA%20AApYPvk99nwSYdBIGHgEUgB3c4BKGdOEPa%20wwOAB8EBk3CR1vZSBJmvRWq0oHkMlAiAhCvYwAA6K6jeTYqFuS6-JAlIiQYBEWAkbDrXp48i3e4-ND-RbwxT0KwMJ7QOCIZQYADqZVMhzcxgZlBabQ6XR6vJeiGAEAgcAA1t9hgFsI52VZBQgADJoLgAcXB4vcIuAYooMpW8oQKrVsE1gIQOscFjiACo2iR3gGg76ElYDX4EABld7YKCwlxHG12h1ytYujVaz262FUWL%20sDvTEFBCF4sIUOcg0aRDyBrsYZ1CD1mZvQO1eqNb5KGsId6i4ituuNLGbJIFc7J4hfdlXcmIQtx2GzYfsUdbCcxpczoA)):

```
class Entity {
  public components: Component[] = [];

  public fetch<T extends Component>(componentType: abstract new() => T): T | undefined {
    return this.components.find(c => c instanceof componentType) as T;
  }
}
// no errors
const weapon = entity.fetch(Weapon); 
const sword = entity.fetch(Sword);
```